# Problemas con el valor de una variable

Tags: javascript, variables

He hecho este código pero el inspector de elementos me dice que `boton` esta si definir, el error exacto es este:

> Uncaught typeerror: Cannot read property onclick of undefined.

La cuestión es que cuando pego el código en el inspector de elementos funciona pero cuando lo guardo en el html no, es como si la variable `boton` perdiera su valor, de hecho lo verifico en el inspector de elementos y cuando lo carga de la web me da error, pero si lo hago paso a paso funciona. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Gracias por adelantado, a continuación os dejo el código:

```
var boton = document.getElementsByClassName('ShowMore')[0];
console.log(boton);
if (boton!=false){
console.log("existe el boton");
boton.onclick("jq('#jqSectionText').toggle();jq(this).toggleClass('ShowLess'); jq(this).toggleClass('ShowMore');jq(this).find('.fa-chevron').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');");
```

Comment: Comprueba la línea ´if(boton!=false){´, tienes sin cerrar el if. Quizá sea ese el fallo

Answer (score 1):

Primero, la comprobación sobre la existencia de un elemento con clase 'ShowMore' debiera ser:

```
var boton = document.getElementsByClassName('ShowMore')[0];
console.log(boton);
if (boton !== undefined){

}
```

Segundo, veo que ya estás ejecutando jQuery, pero en vez de pasarle una función que hace cosas al listener onClick, le pasas un texto gigante que no hace nada. Creo que lo que quieres hacer se escribiría como:

```
var boton = jq('.ShowMore').first();
console.log(boton);
if (boton !== undefined){
  console.log("existe el boton");
  boton.on('click',function() {
    jq('#jqSectionText').toggle();
    jq(this).toggleClass('ShowLess'); 
    jq(this).toggleClass('ShowMore');
    jq(this).find('.fa-chevron').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
  });
```

}

Me parece que toggleClass está deprecated en jQuery 3, pero no tengo idea qué versión estarás usando.

Saludos, espero te sirva.

Comment: No sería mucho mejor hacer un `if(typeof(boton) !== 'undefined')`?

Comment: En este caso sería como lo mismo. Yo uso typeof cuando pruebo variables no declaradas

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos y a ti en especial, creo que el problema es ese y usaré tu solución. Es increíble todo lo que se aprende aquí, una vez más, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

¿Ejecutas ese código en `.ready` de jQuery o `DOMContentLoaded` de JavaScript? Esto puede macar la diferencia ya que, si el script se ejecuta **antes que el DOM sea cargado**, `boton` valdrá `undefined` porque **no hay un DOM** al cual consultar.

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
  // tu código aquí
});
```

o

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // tu código aquí
});
```

También estás cometiendo un error al comprobar si la variable `boton` tiene la referencia esperada. Cuando las funciones selectoras como `getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementsByTagName`, `querySelector`, etc., no encuentran el elemento de acuerdo al selector, devuelven un NodeList vacío o si es una función selectora única, `null`.

En tu caso, la expresión:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ShowMore')
```

Devuelve un NodeList que puede estar vacío **si no se ha encontrado el elemento** o **si el DOM aún no ha cargado**. Si esto ocurre y seleccionas algún índice del NodeList (`[0]`), obtendrás `undefined` **no** `false` (en otros lenguajes inclusive se lanza alguna excepción/error).

Tu código final debería verse de la siguiente manera. Como estás usando jQuery, he escrito tu código usando dicha librería:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
  $('.ShowMore:eq(0)').on('click', function () {
    $('#jqSectionText').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('ShowLess');
    $(this).toggleClass('ShowMore');
    $(this)
      .find('.fa-chevron')
      .toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
  });
});
```

Comment: Ojo, él quiere aplicar el evento solo al primer botó

Comment: Ups, se me pasó. Gracias por indicarlo.